# remote akka actor error to send serializable messages

Tags: scala, serialization, akka

I'm using remote akka actors and I want to send serialized messages, use ObjectOutputStream but have abd error when the local actor send the messages to remote actor, the error is:
java.io.NotRerializableException no configured serialization - bindings for class java.io.ObjectOutputStream
which type of serialization is recommended?

Answer (score 2):

A `java.io.ObjectOutputStream` is not serializable so it can't be sent as a remote message out-of-the-box.  You'll either need to send a different message or write a serializer for that class and configure Akka appropriately.  But, given what an `ObjectOutputStream` is, it doesn't even make sense for an object of that type to be sent over the wire.

Moreover, `java.io.ObjectOutputStream` is effectively mutable and so it absolutely should not be sent as a message in Akka anyways, rendering this whole thing moot.  Just don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create your own `ObjectOutputStream` to send the message. You just a domain message object (e.g., `Person`, `AddItem`, ...) that is serializable to your Akka actors. Akka will take care of sending it over the wire. By default it will use Java serialization (which is not the most efficient).